# Fetching raw data from github wiki

Tags: github, fetch, wiki, raw

How do I fetch raw github wiki file that contains other files?

In my wiki I have 8 links that redirect to other wiki files in the same repo. I got to fetch each individual files with:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/user/repo/file.md
```

But how do I fetch the main file with 8 links? I need it to get names to fetch them later on individually as done above.

For better explanation, whenever I press on wiki page I get:

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
etc...
```

so how do I fetch this page? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I clone a wiki repository ([`git clone https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_REPOSITORY.wiki.git`](https://docs.github.com/en/communities/documenting-your-project-with-wikis/adding-or-editing-wiki-pages)), like the [`thinkaurelius/titan`](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan) one, I get a `Home.textile` file as the homepage of the wiki.

Clone your repository wiki, and you will see your homepage filename, that you can use for getting its raw content.